# Struggling with css stylesheet href specification

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, href

I have an issue with css stylesheet href.

When I add the ref as url:

```
   <link href="http://......" />
```

It doesn't take any effect on my html, even though I can see it in the **document.styleSheets**.

When I am downloading the css file and reference it locally - it works :

```
<link href="./css/test.css" />
```

I've tried to download it with javascript and then inject it to the 
**document.head** as html element:

```
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
style.innerHTML = response;
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

And this work too as well...

- The css href has to be a url, since I need the ability to change it remotely.
- The browser is a Windows Phone WebView running IE as its engine
  I don't understand why its not working.

Comment: Please give me the css url. Can you open that css file directly?

Comment: What is the link for the stylesheet you are trying to load? have you tried adding <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://.....">

Comment: Well, it can be any scripe really. For instance - some script from my google drive :   https://doc-04-cc-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/u6a4ju8pk60kfnu4op6q918pv4fuj5cl/1444708800000/05242910807593990584/*/0B5RCOjxR5lkVQTlRNEpmUUtnc0k?e=download

Comment: The css href has to be a url, since I want to change it on the server and by that to update users' css remotely.

Answer (score 0):

use this format for linking a css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/path" />
```

Also check if your site is running in https. In that case browser will not load http resource due to security.

Comment: If my browser wouldn't download it, how can it be downloaded from javascript?

Comment: try using this path <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//www.css.com/test.css" />  without the http/https. this will load the resource depending on the request

Comment: It didn't work for me, however, I've noticed on document.styleSheet that IE replaced the http/https with ms-appx// prefix - which is local stream convention. I think it might be the problem. Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind if you're using a HTML5 doctype you don't need type="text/css".